# Predict the housing price for first two samples of X_test set and print them.(Hint : Use predict() function)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

As part of learning hands on below is requirement and my code but i am not able to proceed for next step. could any one help to find what is problem in this code?

#Import two modules sklearn.datasets, and #sklearn.model_selection.
#Import numpy and set random seed to 100.

#Load popular Boston dataset from sklearn.datasets module #and assign it to variable boston.

#Split boston.data into two sets names X_train and X_test. #Also, split boston.target into two sets Y_train and Y_test.

#Hint: Use train_test_split method from #sklearn.model_selection; set random_state to 30.
#Print the shape of X_train dataset.

#Print the shape of X_test dataset.

```
import sklearn.datasets as datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(100)

boston = datasets.load_boston()

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(boston.data, boston.target, random_state=30)

print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
```

#Import required module from sklearn.tree.

#Build a Decision tree Regressor model from X_train set and #Y_train labels, with default parameters. Name the model as #dt_reg.

#Evaluate the model accuracy on training data set and print #it's score.

#Evaluate the model accuracy on testing data set and print it's score.

#Predict the housing price for first two samples of X_test #set and print them.(Hint : Use predict() function)

```
dt_reg = DecisionTreeRegressor()
dt_reg = dt_reg.fit(X_train, Y_train)

print('Accuracy of Train Data :', dt_reg.score(X_train,Y_train))
print('Accuracy of Test Data :', dt_reg.score(X_test,Y_test))
predicted = dt_reg.predict(X_test[:2])
print(predicted)
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! I ran your code without any problems. Your code looks fine to me. Please clarify your question and problem here. Feel also free to have a tour here https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is running well, let me know if you need any other help!

[image]

Comment: Could please help me with following step on this same task :                                       
Fit multiple Decision tree regressors on X_train data and Y_train labels with max_depth parameter value changing from 2 to 5.

Evaluate each model accuracy on testing data set.

Hint: Make use of for loop
Print the max_depth value of the model with highest accuracy.

Comment: I tried below but not getting how to print max_dept value with highest accuracy,                                                      maxdepth=6  , for degree in range(2,maxdepth) dt_reg=decisionTreeregressor(max_depth=degree) dt_reg=dt_reg.fit(X_train,Y_train) print("value:", degree,dt_reg.score(X_test, Y_test)